# Множественноe присваивание в python

Tags: python

Начал читать про множественно присваивание и не совсем понял, что и как. Попробовал наюрать код...и совсем ничего не понял.
Пример вывода чисел Фиббоначи на python (с множ.присв-ем):

```
a,b = 0,1
while b<10:
print b;
a,b = b, a+b
```

Компилятор выводит: 1,1,2,3,5,8

Если же я пишу такой код:

```
a=0
b=1
while b<10:
print b
a = b;
b = a+b
```

То компилятор выводит вот это: 1,2,4,8

в чем разница и почему разный результат?

Comment: и в чем заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: "в чем разница и почему разный результат?"

Comment: в вашем случае сумма a + b вычисляется для уже для измененного a (a=b).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a,b = b, a+b
```

эквивалентно

```
c = a + b
a = b
b = c
```

что совсем не похоже на ваш второй пример кода, в котором в итоге a = b и b = b*2 (т.к. a уже b)

Comment: @actionless, вопрос со стороны) Это в Питоне такие вещи сперва высчитываются, потом присваиваются, правильно понял?

В пэхэпэ очень не хватает такого, пользуют такой костыль

    list($a, $b) = array($b, $a + b);

Comment: по immutable типам не вспомню, вроде бы да, но в случае с mutable он просто меняет их указатели местами